# authenticate from a website to an azure mobile app service

Tags: authentication, mobile, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

I have an Azure Mobile App service that I use with my (Cordova and Xamarin) mobile apps. The URL for the Mobile App service is https://gonzo.azurewebsites.net/ (not the real URL). I want to create a website (ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web App)  that connects to my Azure Mobile App service, just like my apps do. I tried publishing it to the gonzo URL but that overwrote my mobile app service and thus I had to restore it. I’d love to know if there is a way to actually make that work.
My next step was to create the website and use a different URL https://kermit.azurewebsites.net/. I use social authentication for my app mobile service. When I debug it locally against localhost, everything works perfectly. The problem that I’m running into is that when I try to login from the published website, regardless of the auth provider (facebook, Microsoft, google), instead of getting to the login UI supplied by the login provider, I get a 403 with the URL looking something like this: https://gonzo.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/facebook/callback?code=long-code.

I thought this can be fixed by allowing the kermit origin in my Azure Mobile App service in CORS. I even tried setting CORS to allow all hosts (*) but that didn’t make a difference. Any idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to create a website (ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web App) that connects to my Azure Mobile App service, just like my apps do. I tried publishing it to the gonzo URL but that overwrote my mobile app service and thus I had to restore it. I’d love to know if there is a way to actually make that work.

Based on your requirement, I assumed that you could deploy your NET Core 2.0 Web App along with your mobile app, at this point your two applications could share the authentication. For Detailed tutorial, you could follow [Deploying multiple virtual directories to a single Azure Website](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2014/09/21/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website/).

> The problem that I’m running into is that when I try to login from the published website, regardless of the auth provider (facebook, Microsoft, google), instead of getting to the login UI supplied by the login provider, I get a 403 with the URL looking something like this: https://gonzo.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/facebook/callback?code=long-code.

According to your description, you are using the [App Service Authentication / Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview). I would recommend you directly access `https://<your-mobile-app-name>.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/<provider-name>` via the browser to make sure you have successfully set up the authentication for your mobile app.
If I understand you correctly that you want to create another Azure Web App to hosting your NET Core 2.0 Website, and your website wants to connect with your mobile app. Here are some approaches, you could refer to them:

- For accessing mobile app in the front-end of your .Net Core web app

  You could leverage the JavaScript SDK for Azure Mobile Apps in your .Net Core web app to access your mobile app. Details you could follow [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-html-how-to-use-client-library). Additionally, if your website would also enable the app service authentication, you could just send `GET https://<your-netcore-webapp-name>.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me` to retrieve the `access_token`, then use the [Client-managed authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#clientflow) for logging with your mobile app in the front-end of your netcore website.
- For accessing mobile app in the back-end of your .Net Core web app

  I assume that your .Net Core web app would also need to enable social authentication via using the App Service Authentication / Authorization, and in the backend of your website you could retrieve the access_token for the current logged user, then you could use [Client-managed authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-dotnet-how-to-use-client-library#clientflow) for logging with your mobile app. The logging request would look like this:

  `POST https://<your-mobile-app-name>.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/<provider-name>`
  `Payload: {"access_token":"<the-access-token-for-the-specific-social-provider>"}`

  Moreover, for retrieving the user logged infos (including the access_token,etc.) from  App Service Authentication / Authorization ([EasyAuth](http://cgillum.tech/2016/02/01/architecture-of-azure-app-service-authentication-authorization/)), you could follow this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42260708/azure-apps-easyauth-claims-with-net-core/42270669#42270669).

Comment: Thanks! I will try the multiple virtual directories approach. I fixed the 403 issue I had with the different URL by adding my new website to the list of "Allowed External Redirect URLs" in the Authentication/Authorization tab in the mobile service