# azure-mobile-apps getting 401 error when calling invokeApi

Tags: cordova, ionic2, google-oauth, azure-mobile-services, asp.net-core-webapi

I am using Azure app services for my Api (ASP.NET Core) and I have an Api Controller like this

```
[Route("api")]
public class PingController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("ping")]
    public string Ping()
    {
        return "Pong";
    }

    [Authorize]
    [HttpGet("claims")]
    public object Claims()
    {
        return User.Claims.Select(c =>
        new
        {
            Type = c.Type,
            Value = c.Value
        });
    }
}
```

Then I am trying to access this from a Ionic2 (TypeScript & Cordova) implementation like this

```
this.client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient('https://mysite.azurewebsites.net/');
 this.client.login('google').then(result=>{
    this.client.invokeApi("claims", {
        body: null,
        method: "get"
    }).done(function (results) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(results));
    }, function (error) {
        let msg = error.message;
        let request = error.request;
        alert(msg+';'+request.status);
    });
});
```

The login screen shows up correctly and the service gets called, but fails with 401 error. It works if I call the 'ping' service. 
The HTTP call has X-ZUMO headers that I think should be good for authentication(?):

```
GET /api/claims HTTP/1.1
Host: mysite.azurewebsites.net
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
ZUMO-API-VERSION: 2.0.0
X-ZUMO-INSTALLATION-ID: 10badf87-...
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
X-ZUMO-AUTH: eyJ0eXAiOiJKV...
accept: application/json
X-ZUMO-VERSION: ZUMO/2.0 (lang=Cordova; os=--; os_version=--; arch=--; version=2.0.0-41128.193844)
Referer: http://localhost:8000/index.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: ARRAffinity=4df5cc005....
```

the Azure app debug log just shows IIS's default 401 screen. saying the resource has been access as 'anonymous'. 
I have used Auth0 before and you have to register JWT Bearer options in app configuration. But for Azure, I don't see any tutorials doing a similar step. So what is that I am missing to get this working?

Comment: Well add the authorization header to your claims request. You are getting a result from the login, use it

Comment: @misha130 that is why the X-ZUMO-AUTH header is there. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview

Answer (score 1):

I wrote about App Service in ASP.NET Core here: https://shellmonger.com/2017/03/02/azure-app-service-authentication-in-an-asp-net-core-application/

Basically - you need to handle the token in .NET Core.  It's not native.

Comment: Thanks. My question was actually duplicate of this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41501612/trouble-getting-claimsprincipal-populated-when-using-easyauth-to-authenticate-ag

Comment: @adrian-hall your repository https://github.com/adrianhall/netcore-server/tree/p5 is down. Code anywhere else?

Comment: I'm no longer with MSFT - the sample was a part of one of the repos that was transferred to MSFT when I left.  Sorry!  I'll update the blog to remove the link

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours, I realized that App Services is not populating the Claims Principal for the ASP.NET Core Application. This means it is not handling the X-ZUMO headers and validating them.

Look at this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41501612/trouble-getting-claimsprincipal-populated-when-using-easyauth-to-authenticate-ag)

The proposed solution is to use the X-ZUMO header to make a call to the /.auth/me service, which returns all the claims and use the response to set the Authentication Context inside your ASP.NET Core application.

This [GitHub](https://github.com/lpunderscore/azureappservice-authentication-middleware) repository now makes this very easy to do. It defines an extension method so that you can get this happen for your application by calling

> app.UseAzureAppServiceAuthentication();