# .NET Core app with Azure App Service Authentication

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0

My webapp is developed with .NET Core and deployed in Azure. I have enabled Azure App Service Authentication and configured it to use Azure Active Directory. 
When I access the webapp I do get redirected to the correct login-page.
After I login I can browse to the endpoint .auth/me and see that claims exists for my user. I can also verify that the request headers below exists with values:

- X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ID-TOKEN
- X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ACCESS-TOKEN
- X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-EXPIRES-ON
- X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-REFRESH-TOKEN

But I'm not able to retrieve these claims in my controller.
Using User.Identity.isAuthenticated is always false and User.Identity.Claims is empty.

How can I make the user authenticated and retrieve the claims?

In theory I could maybe check if the request-header(X-MS-TOKEN-AAD-ID-TOKEN) exist and then retrieve the claims that exists on the endpoint .auth/me but that doesn't really seems like the correct way to go?

Edit:
Am I stumbling on the same issue that is discussed here maybe? ([Trouble getting ClaimsPrincipal populated when using EasyAuth to authenticate against AAD on Azure App Service in a Asp.Net Core web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41501612/trouble-getting-claimsprincipal-populated-when-using-easyauth-to-authenticate-ag))

Comment: Yup, you're doing it right, read the header, unpack the id_token and extract the claims. See this as well - https://stackoverflow.com/a/46765687/4148708. If you don't like this approach, drop EasyAuth and integrate with Azure AD directly (and use ADAL .NET).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Working with user identities in your application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-authentication-overview#working-with-user-identities-in-your-application) states:

> App Service passes some user information to your application by using special headers. External requests prohibit these headers and will only be present if set by App Service Authentication / Authorization. Some example headers include:
>
> - X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-NAME
> - X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-ID
> - X-MS-TOKEN-FACEBOOK-ACCESS-TOKEN
> - X-MS-TOKEN-FACEBOOK-EXPIRES-ON
>
> Code that is written in any language or framework can get the information that it needs from these headers. For ASP.NET 4.6 apps, the **ClaimsPrincipal** is automatically set with the appropriate values.
>
> our application can also obtain additional user details through an HTTP GET on the `/.auth/me` endpoint of your application. A valid token that's included with the request will return a JSON payload with details about the provider that's being used, the underlying provider token, and some other user information.

As Chris Gillum suggested that you could invoke the `/.auth/me` endpoint and retrieve the user claims. You could write your custom middleware to check the `X-MS-CLIENT-PRINCIPAL-ID` header and invoke the `/.auth/me` endpoint and set the user claims manually. Here is the detailed code sample, you could refer to this similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42260708/azure-apps-easyauth-claims-with-net-core/42270669#42270669).

Moreover, you could modify your application and explicitly add authentication middleware instead of using App Service Authentication / Authorization (EasyAuth) as evilSnobu commented. For this approach, you could use the ASP.Net Core OpenID Connect middleware, details you could follow the tutorials below:

[Integrating Azure AD (v2.0 endpoint) into an ASP.NET Core web app](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore-v2)

[Integrating Azure AD into an ASP.NET Core web app](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore)