# Mapping Azure AD Claims into my AspNet Core App

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, claims

I have a webapp which is protected by Azure AD in the portal.

If I go to this url for example: **myapp.azurewebsites.net/.auth/me**, I can see the available claims in my browser.

If I look in the ClaimPrincipal, they are empty.

My Startup.cs is very basic:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Why is there no mapping from what I see in my brother to the webapp?

Comment: see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41501612/trouble-getting-claimsprincipal-populated-when-using-easyauth-to-authenticate-ag

Comment: Yes, same issue. Thanks